# javascript - SweetAlert2 add dynamic options to select input

Tags: javascript, arrays, sweetalert2

I want to add dynamic options to the input of the select type sweetalert2.
I want to pass to that select an array that I get from an ajax request.
How should I do this? I have not found documentation about it.
From already thank you very much.

Comment: Additional details will make it easier for someone to provide a helpful answer. Check out [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some great tips. What have you tried so far?